# Многопоточность и параллельность при запуске внешнего EXE несколько раз

Tags: c#, многопоточность, инспекция-кода, распараллеливание

Добрый день, уважаемое сообщество.

Прошу провести *code review* и дать совет. Есть программа.
Ей надо запустить один и тот же внешний EXE файл **N** раз с разными входными параметрами. Дождаться окончания выполнения всех запущенных процессов и собрать результаты в единый, допустим, массив.

Как использовать параллелизм  и асинхронность (если последняя тут нужна) с максимальной эффективностью?

Я пока сделала такое решение:

```
List<Tuple<int, int, string, string>> processignDataList = ... //список кортежей с входными данными
Task[] stackTasks = new Task[processignDataList.Count]; // массив всех тасков
List<Tuple<int, string>> tasksResults = new List<Tuple<int, string>>(); //список кортежей с результатами отработки тасков
int i = 0; // счетчик, нужен только для указания элемента массива

foreach (Tuple<int, int, string, string> pair in processignDataList) {
  stackTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => tasksResults.Add(Tuple.Create(pair.Item1, pairProcessing(cSettings, pair))));
  i++; 
}
Task.WaitAll(stackTasks);
```

Метод `string pairProcessing()`:

- берет свойства из специального объекта `cSettings`, входные параметры
  из pair,
- запускает EXE как Process - `process.Start();`
- там же находится ограничение от бесконечного зависания - `process.WaitForExit(3000)`
- потом проверка, что `process.Close();`
- анализ `StandardOutput`, и на его основе
- формирование некой строки и ее возврат как результата работы метода `pairProcessing`

Достигаю ли я с таким решением запуска нескольких экземпляров EXE и параллельного их выполнения? Нужны ли какие-то дополнительные пометки методу `pairProcessing()`, есть к нему какие-то требования или он может быть любым? Знаете ли вы решения лучше? (а решение лучше есть всегда...) Есть ли косяки? 
Спасибо.

Comment: "Достигаю ли я с таким решением запуска нескольких экземпляров EXE и параллельного их выполнения?" - проще попробовать и посмотреть. IMHO, подход правильный: запустить процессы и ждать завершения всех.

Comment: По-моему, таски здесь не нужны. Вместо списка тасков создайте список процессов. Запускайте и дожидайтесь окончания процессов, а не тасков.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Посмотреть... Мысль простая, но эффективная, спасибо. https://wtf.jpg.wtf/c7/86/1475843334-c7864396b7185909d2510973235fc4d6.png - есть многопоточность и три отдельных процесса. Сейчас еще проверю, можно ли из этой цепочки выкинуть таски и оставить одни процессы, как советует Александр.

Comment: Если просто список процессов, то должно пойти, если вы не читаете их stdout. (А если читаете, надо подумать.)

Comment: @VladD вообще читаю. У меня в таск, помимо запуска процесса, входит чтение его stdout-а, анализ и, возможно, появятся еще какие-то действия. Мне без тасков неудобно будет.

Comment: @Natalia я, если честно, ничего не знаю о тасках. У меня либо системные потоки, либо системные же процессы.

Comment: @Natalia вывод в файл через перенаправление вывода?

Comment: @Natalia: А как именно читаете? Это важно, покажите код. В зависимости от этого может быть, а может и не быть нужен отдельный Task.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вывод в String. а потом в лог и на всякие обработки.  `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; ... process.Start(); output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); process.WaitForExit(cSettings.getWTimeout());`

Comment: @Natalia: Так по идее будет работать. Если вы не читаете ещё и `StandardError`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас нет синхронизации доступа к `tasksResults` - тут может быть неприятная гонка.

Во-вторых, если процессов будет много - у вас могут закончиться потоки в пуле, что нежелательно ограничит параллелизм. Впрочем, слишком много процессов все равно не смогут работать параллельно.

---

Первая проблема решается довольно просто - вместо записи в список внутри задачи надо позволить задаче вернуть значение:

```
List<Task<Tuple<int, string>>> stackTasks = new List<Task<Tuple<int, string>>>();

foreach (Tuple<int, int, string, string> pair in processignDataList) {
  stackTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Tuple.Create(pair.Item1, pairProcessing(cSettings, pair))));
}

Tuple<int, string>[] tasksResults = Task.WhenAll(stackTasks).Result;
```

Также можно воспользоваться linq:

```
Tuple<int, string>[] tasksResults = Task.WhenAll(
  from pair in processignDataList
  select Tuple.Create(pair.Item1, pairProcessing(cSettings, pair)))
).Result;
```

или так:

```
Tuple<int, string>[] tasksResults = Task.WhenAll(
  processignDataList.Select(pair => Tuple.Create(pair.Item1, pairProcessing(cSettings, pair))))
).Result;
```

---

Для решения второй проблемы надо переходить от задач к потокам. Или увеличить размер пула потоков при помощи [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads(v=vs.110).aspx)